# Redis Startup issues on Debian Stretch (9)

Tags: linux, redis

Actually I'm on my way to switch to debian 9 for the new production servers of the company and want to provision them with ansible. So far, everything works fine, but now I'm stuck with redis-server.

By default, Debian 9 comes with redis version 3.2. I'm installing the package via `apt-get install redis-server`. After that, redis starts up as a daemon in the background. Now I want to apply some custom configuration, like binding to 2 different IPs (127.0.0.1 and the server IP).

After changing this as well as the `daemonize` option (to `yes`), redis is no longer willing to start in the background. Whenever doing either `service redis-server start` or `/etc/init.d/redis-server start`, the command just stucks.

`journalctl -xe` tells me, that the pid file is not readable (`redis-server.service: PID file /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid not readable (yet?) after start-post: No such file or directory`) even though it should be created according to init.d script:

```
start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    mkdir -p $RUNDIR
    touch $PIDFILE
    chown redis:redis $RUNDIR $PIDFILE
    chmod 755 $RUNDIR
```

After all, I can see, that both `service redis-server start` and `/etc/init.d/redis-server` are starting the server and I'm also able to connect to the server via `redis-cli`. But the damn process stucks.

Can anyone help? If you need further information, just let me know. I'll provide what ever possible if this solves the problem!

best
Chris

Comment: This is probably a better question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). It sound sliek you have a configuration issue, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation on a Centos 7 server.

The resolution was to change `supervised` from **no** to **auto**

```html
# By default Redis does not run as a daemon. Use 'yes' if you need it.
# Note that Redis will write a pid file in /var/run/redis.pid when daemonized.
daemonize yes

# If you run Redis from upstart or systemd, Redis can interact with your
# supervision tree. Options:
#   supervised no      - no supervision interaction
#   supervised upstart - signal upstart by putting Redis into SIGSTOP mode
#   supervised systemd - signal systemd by writing READY=1 to $NOTIFY_SOCKET
#   supervised auto    - detect upstart or systemd method based on
#                        UPSTART_JOB or NOTIFY_SOCKET environment variables
# Note: these supervision methods only signal "process is ready."
#       They do not enable continuous liveness pings back to your supervisor.
supervised auto
```

When you run the process as daemon it need to interact with systemd for process management (if I read well some documentation).

Thanks